# make [subsetting] a synonym of [subset]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I believe these two conjugate words carry the same meaning (from set theory) in every programming context. Those folks [asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subsetting) [subsetting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subsetting) on SO seem to always mean selecting a subset of data (which matches up with the tag wiki for [subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subset)), since 64 of the 66 "subsetting" questions are also tagged with R, a statistical package.

Here's where to vote: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/subset/synonyms

Comment: I agree with the OP. I would vote if I could in the link provided ...